# Having nano-scale holes in metal, possible today?

Tags: laser, molecules, nanoscience

I am considering to design a gas filtering system that is based on the size of gas molecules.

Basic idea is to flow mixed gas in a long pipe, and to allow CO2 to get of pipe through nano-size holes from pipe before reaching to other side. (Yes I know, still some CO2 will reach to other side.)

I actually couldn't have found an exact and trusted answer about the diameter of CO2 though, I saw somewhere it was saying something like 7 nm.

As far as I see, there are some businesses those do micro level drilling with laser. Is it possible with today's technology (not that expensive to 3D nano print it) to create holes where only CO2 size gases can pass?

Extra question if possible: Any business you know who can do that onto steel?

---

I have learned that "membrane" are used for gas scrubbing purposes. They are based on poly* materials though. So, not as tough as a steel with holes on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [CO$_2$ molecule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) is more like 0.5nm long and 0.25nm wide, so you're not going to create your holes with a laser or any imminent development of [nanolithography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanolithography).

A better bet would be to grow a crystal with pores of the correct size. For example you could probably find a [zeolite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeolite) with a suitable pore size.